# auto resize multiple forms according to system resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resize, autosize

I am working on windows application..i have two forms like this:
**first form name: Visitorinfo

second form name:VisitorExitsign**
in parent form i am calling this form together.. my screen resolution is `1366X768(Recommended)`

i am calling my two forms together like this:

```
frmVE = new VisitorInfo();
frmVE.Location = new Point(0, 0);
frmVE.MdiParent = this;
frmVE.Show();

frmVX = new VisitorExitsign();
frmVX.Location = new Point(780, 0);
frmVX.MdiParent = this;
frmVX.Show();
```

in my screen resolution i am getting this form very clear ,like this:

[image]

my client side system having different screen resolution.so for testing i changed my system resolution and i opend this form again..but this time i am not getting this in proper fitting..now i am getting the same like this:
[image]

how i resize my two forms according to system resolution....while opening this forms together i want to fit this forms with screen resolution..

any help is very appreciable...Thanks

Comment: Do both forms need to be visible at once, or could you put them on separate tabs, for example, maximising the screen space available to both regardless of the resolution?

Comment: in my first image you can see my two forms

Comment: Indeed, but do they both realistically need to be visible at the same time? Or can one be hosted within the other to maximise horizontal space as scrolling vertically could be an acceptable compromise on smaller displays?

Comment: yes sir,i need to visible this two forms same time..and scrolling could not be acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control.Dock Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to ensure that it is resized depending on a resolution.

Comment: where i have to add this code? in parant form or child form